# How to search between two dates on a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I filter records on a `DataGridView` using a date range with `DateTimePickers`?

This is my code so far, but when I click the button it does nothing:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource.Filter = "FECHA >= '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' and FECHA <= '" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "'"
End Sub
```

This is the code to set up the `BindingSource`:

```
Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components) 
CType(Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit() 
Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource.DataMember = "Consulta_Detalle" 
Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource.DataSource = Me.AtlánticoDataSet
```

Comment: Can you show the code to set up the `BindingSource`?

Comment: Try to format the `DateTimePicker` to an actual date like so `format(DateTimePicker1.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")` I don't know if this is the case but I had similar problems and solved them with this

Comment: @djv This is the code i have for the BindingSource in the Designer:


`Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)`


`CType(Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()`


`Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource.DataMember = "Consulta_Detalle"`


`Me.Consulta_DetalleBindingSource.DataSource = Me.AtlánticoDataSet`


@3vts I tried to format the DateTimePicker but it didnt work either.

Comment: What error are you getting?